# Navbar not updating on successful User Signin

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, rails-api, vue-cli-3

I am building my first Vue-Cli 3 project with a Rails 6 Api as the backend.

I have a nav component that is supposed to update on successful user sign in, right now when a user signs in it redirects to the user dashboard but the nav stays as the logged nav view. It will successfully change when I force refresh the page.

Being so new to Vue this could be a small issue, however I am struggling to find any references on this issue.

I am using Axios Axios-Vue and JWTSessions to handle the tokens / sessions

here is my Navigation.vue component code:

```
<template>
  <div class="font-sans antialiased">
    <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-loadze-blue p-6 fixed w-full">
      <div class="flex items-center flex-no-shrink text-gray-900 mr-6">
        <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight text-white">Loadze.co</span>
      </div>
      <div class="block sm:hidden">
        <button @click="toggle" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-lighter border-teal-light hover:text-white hover:border-white">
          <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div :class="open ? 'block': 'hidden'" class="w-full flex-grow sm:flex sm:items-center sm:w-auto">
        <div class="text-sm sm:flex-grow">
          <router-link to="/home" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white mr-4" v-if="!signedIn()">Home</router-link>
          <router-link to="/about" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white mr-4" v-if="!signedIn()">About</router-link>
          <router-link to="/features" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white mr-4" v-if="!signedIn()">Features</router-link>
          <router-link to="/pricing" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white mr-4" v-if="!signedIn()">Pricing</router-link>
          <router-link to="/contact" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white mr-4" v-if="!signedIn()">Contact Us</router-link>
        </div>
        <div>
          <router-link to="/signup" class="text-sm no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white mr-4" v-if="!signedIn()">Sign up</router-link>
          <router-link to="/signin" class="text-sm no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white mr-4" v-if="!signedIn()">Sign in</router-link>
          <a href="#" @click.prevent="signOut" class="text-sm no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-teal-lighter hover:text-white mr-4" v-if="signedIn()">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Navigation',
  data () {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle () {
      this.open = !this.open
    },
    setError (error, text) {
      this.error = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error) || text
    },
    signedIn () {
      return localStorage.signedIn
    },
    signOut () {
      this.$http.secured.delete('/signin')
        .then(response => {
          delete localStorage.csrf
          delete localStorage.signedIn
          this.$router.replace('/')
        })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, 'Can not sign out'))
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

and this is the Signin.vue component (script the form code is long.. please let me know if you need to see it) code:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Signin',
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      error: ''
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.checkSignedIn()
  },
  updated () {
    this.checkSignedIn()
  },
  methods: {
    signin () {
      this.$http.plain.post('/signin', { email: this.email, password: this.password })
        .then(response => this.signinSuccessful(response))
        .catch(error => this.signinFailed(error))
    },
    signinSuccessful (response) {
      if (!response.data.csrf) {
        this.signinFailed(response)
        return
      }
      localStorage.scrf = response.data.csrf
      localStorage.signedIn = true
      this.error = ''
      this.$router.replace('/dashboard')
    },
    signinFailed (error) {
      this.error = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error) || ''
      delete localStorage.csrf
      delete localStorage.signedIn
    },
    checkSignedIn () {
      if (localStorage.signedIn) {
        this.$router.replace('/dashboard')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a function for your conditional display (`v-if="!signedIn()"`) but the function returns nothing meaning nothing is reactively rendered within the template.

Try to add a new data property which can be updated on signin:

```html
<template>
  ...
  <div class="text-sm sm:flex-grow">
    <router-link to="/home" v-if="!isSignedIn">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about" v-if="!isSignedIn">About</router-link>
    <router-link to="/features" v-if="!isSignedIn">Features</router-link>
    <router-link to="/pricing" v-if="!isSignedIn">Pricing</router-link>
    <router-link to="/contact" v-if="!isSignedIn">Contact Us</router-link>
  </div>
  ...
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Signin',
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      error: '',
      isSignedIn: false // <= here
    }
  },
  //...
  methods: {
    signin () {
      this.$http.plain.post('/signin', { email: this.email, password: this.password })
        .then(response => {
          this.signinSuccessful(response)
          this.isSignedIn = true // <= and here
        }).catch(error => this.signinFailed(error))
    },
    //...
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in your logout's function, you can set the `isSignedIn` back to false.

Comment: Just out of the house for now.. thanks for this explanation and assistance!! I’ll mess around with it tonight and I’ll award best when I get it hooked up!! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For your localStorage object to be reactive, it must be part of the components data or computed properties.
The simplest solution would be storing authentication state in vuex and then supplying it to your components using a vuex mapGetter. You then update the state with a vuex action when the user signs in.
If you are not familiar with vuex there is an example on their website that should be sufficient for this.

Comment: it sorta makes sense but as a total Vue noob can you explain or give an example on how to do it? this is sorta like chineese to me.. lol..